# mount usb disk via udisksctl need root privilege

Tags: linux, mount, udisks

I don't know why, but on my ubuntu 16.04 laptop, `udisksctl` can work properly without `root` privilege. However, when I plug this disk to centos 7, the execution of same command needs root privilege and I get:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat ===
Authentication is required to mount Hitachi HTS542512K9SA00 (/dev/sdc1)
Authenticating as: root
```

I wonder why the same command executes differently on these two system, and how can I get rid of the privilege check?

Comment: Thanks your for your comment! It is my mistake that I didn't clear my question.

Answer (score 0):

See https://superuser.com/a/1192349 and replace `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system` with `org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-other-seat`. Same for the unmount-action. But be warned: a seat belongs to a user session thus mount-other-seat very likely mounts concurrently. In turn two different user sessions can write to the same device. In addition another user can peek into the device.

(Filesystems with sophisticated access control limit the effects dramatically. But the average FAT filesystem/ thumb drive has no additional means of read nor write protection.)

It could be necessary to adjust group membership or even groups at all. The link above uses group `wheel` which is common for `su`/ `sudo` and maybe also too general. Other distributions provide a dedicated group for pluggable devices, e.g. group `plugdev`.

Also, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424539/560724) provides more or less the same solution with some additional details.